# Books for learning how to build fixed-wing RC planes?

Tags: resources

What are some books or reading resources I can use to learn how to build my own fixed-wing RC aircraft? Many years ago, I used to work on a fixed-wing RC aircraft, but only as a programmer for some of its onboard instruments. I am interested in how the physical frame of the aircraft is usually built, and how the electrical components are wired to produce a flyable RC aircraft. Can you recommend some books?

Educational background: first-year university physics, first-year university mathematics, semi-competent programming skills, I have a little bit of experience with using saws, bench drills, lathes, etc. in a school workshop environment.

I don't mind dense and heavy reading.

Comment: I've never been into books (which doesn't mean there are no good ones) but I can recommend the FliteTest YouTube-channel. They do all sorts of stuff with RC planes. Some of their stuff is more on the experimental side but they also have great beginner videos.

Comment: As Bastian said, these guys are a great resource. looks like they put this book out a few years ago so the info may be a bit dated...but still relevant. I have not read the book.                                                                                                                                  The Flite Test Book of RC Airplanes: Everything you need to know before flying R/C Paperback – November 15, 2018
by James Whomsley (Author)